# Is it possible to measure the concrete workability by a mobile app one day?

Tags: civil-engineering, concrete, reinforced-concrete, numerical-methods, prestressed-concrete

After studying all methods that can measure the concrete slump, I found 62 devices that service this purpose at the same time these devices are expensive and not practical enough, for this reason the mobile applications will be better than devices in this field.
From here I discussed a new idea for an app to measure the concrete slump without any physical efforts or wasting time by using some numerical methods,and to advance my research I need to see the different comments on this idea.
Please check [this link](https://www.academia.edu/44368548/My_suggestion_for_the_concrete_trucks_companies) to see the small draft.

Comment: So, get some concrete samples and test them using the classic methods (such as cone slump) and see how accepted results compare to your method.